# Jmeter chrome drive config

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jmeter

I am newbie to the jmeter, currently working on a project where i have to write a jmeter script for complete flow of web-application. i have wrote using the recording feature of the Jmeter but the project requirement has been change to web browser type of execution. Need information how to convert a jmeter project to web browser type of execution

Answer (score 1):

JMeter records script on HTTP level, not UI level (i.e. HTTP requests browser sends to server, and responses received from server). So it's mostly the same for all types of browser, except where your application behavior differs, based on browser.

Such recorded script also runs on HTTP level and you cannot convert it back to browser / UI level.

You can [record Selenium script](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-ide/record-and-playback-selenium-ide-test-case/) on UI level though, and run it in JMeter. See similar question answered here: [How to integrate JMeter with Selenium WebDriver for Load testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211732/how-to-integrate-jmeter-with-selenium-webdriver-for-load-testing)

If you simply need to record your script while using application in Chrome, then set proxy to Jmeter in Chrome as described [here](http://nadimsaker.blogspot.ca/2015/06/jmeter-how-to-configure-your-browser.html)
and re-record your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to convert JMeter tests into "web browser" execution type, the only thing you can do is to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to your Test Plan and configure it to send [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header of browser(s) you need to mimic, check out i.e. [List of User Agent Strings](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) for exact details.

If you need to perform GUI-based testing i.e. kick off a real browser and perform user operations you will need to switch to another tool, like:

- [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (probably the most popular one, moreover there is a JMeter integration with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/))
- [Watir](http://watir.com/)
- [Sahi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sahi/)

There are also "headless" browsers which don't have GUI however they are fully functional web browsers which can be automated:

- [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)
- [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have consider the selenium over the jmeter for UI type of testing.